# Centering an Image in one of the two columns in a two-column format

Tags: overleaf

I have two long images, which I want to fit in a single page. So I want to put two images in two columns.
Using the below code I can put the images in two columns but the images are aligned to the left.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{center}
    \centering
    \makebox[\linewidth][c]{\includegraphics[angle=90, scale = 0.08]{model.png}}
    \caption{Network Model}
\end{center}
\end{multicols}{2}
\end{figure}
```

How can I make the images to be perfectly centered?

Or is there any other way to put two images, which are as long as the page length, in two separate columns and on the same page?

Comment: Does each of the images need an individual caption (figure 1 and figure 2) or do you want a shared caption with (or without?) subcaptions? Which documentclass do you use?

Comment: you have not provided a usable example to allow us to see the problem but any of center \centering or [c] would center and you used all three...

Comment: @leandrils both the images need individual caption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


%%% indicated page layout, do not use in real document
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=15cm]{model.png}
\caption{Network Model}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm, height=15cm]{model.png}
\caption{Network Model}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]